# Unable to assign any single character to a char *ptr declared in C

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to assign a single inside char *ptr and then print the changed value. But it is giving segmentation fault. But don't see the issue if the same is declared as ptr[32] instead of *ptr;

```
int main () {
    char *ptr = "abcdefghijklm";
    ptr[2] = "q";
    printf("%s",ptr);
}
```

Any guess what is going wrong here?

Comment: Basically you need to study arrays, then pointers, then strings, in that order. `ptr[2] = "q"` is also invalid syntax.

Comment: Are you asking for C or C++? In both languages this code is broken, but for different reasons. And each language has its own different solution.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, prefer to use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays can underflow, or overflow and may need to be reallocated.  All this is taken care of for you with the `std::string` class.  The C language doesn't have `std::string`.

Comment: Since you are modifying the data, you should make the declaration `char ptr[] = /*...*/;`  This will allow you to change the contents of the `ptr` array.